# How to get CSS multi-column layout to use the appropriate width when using auto fixed-width columns?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

Is there any way to make the [CSS Multi-column Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) have its appropriate width automatically?

```
.collection {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-column-count: auto;
  -webkit-column-width: 100px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
}
.collection > div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zBsBG/

When using 12 elements, it's now currently automatically setting the `.collection` element's width to the viewport's width.

I'd like for it to just have its proper width, depending on how many columns are automatically made. When it's 3 columns wide, for example, it should be around 300px wide (not the viewport's width).

Am I missing something?

Edit: While I know I can specify a width for the `.collection` element,
but that defeats the purpose of setting the column width specifically and count to auto. I want it to be variable-width.

This would be easy to workaround manually with JavaScript, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have specified `height: 100%`, which means that the `div`elements will attempt to fill the `.collection` element vertically first. By removing the height attribute, columns will balance properly along the width: as such: http://jsfiddle.net/QeD77/

**EDIT: Remade the fiddle using JS to balance width:** http://jsfiddle.net/tG4P6/4/

Comment: The width of the container element is still the width of the entire document in your referenced fiddle.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle. I could only get this to work with JS, unfortunately, but it does work as I believe you had intended.

Comment: I don't see any additional revisions to your fiddle. Sadly, I'm thinking a JS-approach will be necessary, however. I'll probably just recreate the multi-column thing in entirety using JS just for better, more reliable browser compatibility. Cheers!

Comment: Uh oh. Must have forgotten to save it. Well, I have remade the snippet and attached the new link.